# modelsummary and multiple comparisons from marginaleffects

Tags: r, modelsummary, r-marginaleffects

```
dat <- mtcars
dat$cyl <- as.factor(dat$cyl)
dat$am <- as.logical(dat$am)
dat$carb <- as.factor(dat$carb)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl + am+carb, data = dat)
mm_dat <- marginaleffects::comparisons(mod,variables =  list(carb="pairwise"),
                                        by="am",cross = T)

modelsummary(mm_dat,
             title = "Estimated Marginal Means",
             estimate = "{estimate} [{conf.low}, {conf.high}]",
             statistic = NULL,
             group = term ~ am)
```

Any idea how I can retrieve the results from marginaleffects into a summary with the estimates from mm_dat? I only get the length of the individual vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 1.2.0.9001 of `modelsummary` (only available from Github at the time of writing), you can do this:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(marginaleffects)

dat <- mtcars
dat$cyl <- as.factor(dat$cyl)
dat$am <- as.logical(dat$am)
dat$carb <- as.factor(dat$carb)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl + am+carb, data = dat)

cmp <- comparisons(
    mod,
    variables = list(carb = "sequential"),
    by = "am",
    cross = TRUE)

modelsummary(
    cmp,
    output = "markdown",
    shape = am + contrast_carb ~ model,
    estimate = "{estimate} [{conf.low}, {conf.high}]",
    statistic = NULL
)
```

| am | contrast_carb | Model 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | mean(2) - mean(1) | -0.517 [-3.513, 2.480] |
| TRUE | mean(3) - mean(2) | -0.029 [-4.183, 4.126] |
| TRUE | mean(4) - mean(3) | -1.718 [-6.405, 2.969] |
| TRUE | mean(6) - mean(4) | 0.204 [-6.683, 7.092] |
| TRUE | mean(8) - mean(6) | 1.814 [-7.380, 11.007] |
| FALSE | mean(2) - mean(1) | -0.517 [-3.513, 2.480] |
| FALSE | mean(3) - mean(2) | -0.029 [-4.183, 4.126] |
| FALSE | mean(4) - mean(3) | -1.718 [-6.405, 2.969] |
| FALSE | mean(6) - mean(4) | 0.204 [-6.683, 7.092] |
| FALSE | mean(8) - mean(6) | 1.814 [-7.380, 11.007] |
| Num.Obs. |  | 32 |
| R2 |  | 0.840 |
| R2 Adj. |  | 0.774 |
| AIC |  | 168.2 |
| BIC |  | 184.3 |
| Log.Lik. |  | -73.098 |
| F |  | 12.793 |
| RMSE |  | 2.38 |

Comment: Thanks-would indeed be great if you manage to make it work straight "out of the box"

Comment: @Misha I edited my answer to reflect the new development version of `modelsummary`, which works out-of-the-box. Install with `remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")`

Comment: Wonderful--worked like a charm on my original problem as well. Thx